# Тире после "когда"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Конструкция:

> Когда Василий видит тебя в этом платье, замечает все изменения в тебе,
>   обращает внимание на твои новые серьги, макияж, укладку(,) – скорее
>   всего, он уже мысленно подбирает для тебя обручальное кольцо.

Нужна ли запятая в таком предложении или достаточно тире?

Comment: Извините, но _после **когда**_ тире в этом предложении совершенно не нужно (и спрашиваете Вы, собственно, про запятую). Думаю, что Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Нужно. Оно интонационное (эмоционально подчёркивает следующую контрастную [с переломным поворотом] часть) и отделяет главное предложение от запятых между однородным дополнениями, исключая возможность примыкания к ним вводного слова.

Comment: После слова "когда" тире не нужно — я только ЭТО имела в виду.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Аа. Так вы про титулку. Ну так подправьте. Может, тире после придаточного с "когда" - сохраняется оригинальный смысл, описывающий особенность предложения. Не всегда в титулке пишут сам вопрос. Здесь как тема, а не вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

*Когда Василий видит тебя в этом платье, замечает все изменения в тебе, обращает внимание на твои новые серьги, макияж, укладку, – **скорее всего, он уже мысленно подбирает для тебя обручальное кольцо.***

1. **Может, поставить тире вместо запятой**  ввиду распространенности придаточной части? По Розенталю это  5) обилие запятых, на фоне которых тире выступает как более выразительный знак.

   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Вообще-то все проблемы здесь решились бы, если использовать союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, тире как раз и заменит местоименную часть союза. Пауза же там просто необходима, в том числе для выразительности. Но это в устной речи, а что на письме?

2. Ведь **тире** может обозначать любую **присоединительную** конструкцию. Между придаточным и главным находится **вводное слово,** может,  оно  относится к первой части?  Так что **трудно определить**, где кончается придаточное и начинается главное. Не читать же предложение несколько раз, чтобы разобраться в его грамматике.
3. Поэтому ставим **единый знак "запятая и тире",** обозначая главную и придаточную часть, так как другим  образом сделать это весьма затруднительно.

Главное назначение пунктуационного знака – это внесение **ясности в грамматику и смысл предложения**, а не  обязательное следование правилам (так как правила не могут учесть все возможные ситуации).

Comment: "*Может, оно относится к первой части?*" — каким образом? (Это просто нелепо.) Если так рассуждать, то можно всегда ставить тире с запятой. Разве такое предложение можно считать полностью корректным? *Когда Василий видит тебя в этом платье, замечает все изменения в тебе, обращает внимание на твои новые серьги, макияж, укладку – скорее всего, то он уже мысленно подбирает для тебя обручальное кольцо.* Бредовый вариант, так никто не воспримет. Тире с запятой следует ставить в крайнем случае, а не использовать всегда как страховку.

Comment: Используем оценочную лексику, да?  Нелепо, бредовый. Ладно, больше я вами не занимаюсь, ввиду неблагодарности, и так много внимания уделила. Вот учитесь у А. Сп. - она не побоялась сказать, что была неправа. Вот это поступок, не каждый на него способен. А теперь об этом вопросе. Здесь как раз  - тот самый крайний случай. Вы "то" не подставляйте, не надо. Может, Василий работает  парикмахером-визажистом и укладкой с макияжем в первую очередь интересуется.

Comment: А меня вот что интересует: вы вот две страницы  правил переписали, чтобы объяснить один знак и лишить бедного читателя возможности быстро разобраться с предложением. Ничего не говорите ни про интонацию, ни про здравый смысл. В любом случае у нас есть возможность смыслового деления предложения на части. На это правило всегда можно сослаться, даже без перечня всех случаев (на две страницы). Кстати, я часто встречаю ваш "страховочный" прием в книгах, надо будет составить картотеку

Comment: Не согласен. У Розенталя нет такого между придаточным и главным. Там части связаны, а этот знак не к месту. И довольно очевидно, к чему относится вводное слово. Давайте лучше будем все вводные слова на границе предложений выделять тире с запятой, не разбираясь.

Comment: На этот ответ у меня около часа ушло, а собирался отвечать, анализируя материал, неделю. Просто в пень это всё. Спасибо. Отвечайте тут всем сами. Умнее вас тут же никого нет.

Comment: Ага, сейчас. У меня и времени-то нет, чтобы всем отвечать. И вообще, знаете, как надо относиться к жизни? С юмором!  И смотреть на себя как бы со стороны, быть наблюдателем. У меня тоже не всегда получается так делать, но я стараюсь. Один книжный герой, когда его очень уж все доставали, сочинял "лимерик" - краткий стишок, в котором изображал трудную ситуацию в комическом виде. Это его очень успокаивало.

Comment: Вот что вас сейчас расстроило? Оба варианта знаков (тире и запятая с тире) - авторские, неосновные.  Вы можете выбрать тире (нормальное решение), мне нравится запятая и тире. Для разбивки на смысловые части это очень удобный знак. Надо просто понаблюдать, насколько часто он встречается. Оба решения допустимы, так что не стоит выбирать лучшее. Я видела этот вопрос в Интернете, там на него вообще никто не ответил. И еще. Здесь длинные ответы вообще мало кто читает, поэтому за них никто не голосует. Лучше писать покороче.

Comment: Просто совсем не вижу двусмысленности. Разбивка на смысловые части СПП, в котором предложения тесно связаны подчинительной связью, - не есть хорошо (разъединение цельного). Другое дело пример в конце моего ответа. Часто вижу тире перед вводным словом на границе частей, но тире с запятой не встречал.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, здесь, скорее, можно убрать тире, чем запятую, потому что это обычное придаточное предложение с союзом перед главным предложением.

Если верить *справочнику Розенталя* (раздел «Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении») постановку тире можно оправдать только интонационным выделением или большей заметностью тире на фоне обилия запятых в предложении. В этом случае запятая не нужна.

Ни под один из случаев постановки запятой и тире как единого знака пунктуации это предложение, кажется, тоже не попадает: ни однородных придаточных, ни повторяющихся слов, ни «перелома» конструкции здесь нет.

Comment: Ну чисто теоретически интонационное тире здесь может быть. Может, я здесь выделяю паузой. В этом случае тире нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна.

Розенталь:
Тире употребляется перед вводным словом в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой, если вводное слово стоит между двумя частями предложения и может по смыслу быть отнесено или к предшествующей, или к последующей части, например:
*Он любил меня, — кажется, за то, что я всегда готов был слушать его излияния.

Собака исчезла, — наверно, ее пырнули ножом.*
Иногда дополнительный знак подчеркивает пояснительные или причинно-следственные отношения между частями предложения, например:
*Дети прекратили игры, — очевидно, звонок на урок прозвучал.*
*Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — должно быть, хочет зажечь огонь* (Гладков).

В последних двух примерах после тире вывод из первой части. Но части не связаны подчинительной связью — они самостоятельны. После тире будто комментарий к первому предложению (что подобно словам автора, при которых такая же пунктуация).

И отдельный пункт Розенталя про этот же вывод [итог] (но более выраженный):
Тире ставится перед вводным словом после запятой в качестве дополнительного знака, если следующая за вводным словом часть предложения подытоживает сказанное в предшествующей части, например:
*Исполнение роли подкупает своей непосредственностью, захватывает своей правдивостью, горячо волнует, — стало быть, цель достигнута.

Он был молод, строен, с тонкими чертами лица, большими выразительными глазами, — так сказать, настоящий красавец.*

Ещё тире с запятой ставится при переломе конструкции:
*Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку* (пример Розенталя).
После придаточного предложения ожидается главное, а вместо него следует как бы вывод.

В нашем примере запятая стоять не должна, потому что:
1) перелома конструкции нет;
2) понятно, что "скорее всего" относится именно к части после тире;
3) нет оборота, который нужно закрыть;
4) между частями подчинительная связь (тесная) — дополнительный знак там только мешает, увеличенная пауза не к месту.

Если убрать слово "когда" (и подчинительную связь) и переделать предложение соответственно, то по аналогии с примерами Розенталя (а ситуация действительно похожа) можно поставить запятую и тире, так как имеется вывод из первой части (который похож на комментарий):
*Василий увидел тебя в этом платье, заметил все изменения в тебе, обратил внимание на твои новые серьги, макияж, укладку, – скорее всего, он уже мысленно подбирает для тебя обручальное кольцо.* || В некоторой мере даже ощущается перелом конструкции.